# Which correlation test should I use? ANOVA? PCA? Other?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, ecology, climate

I have the following problem and some help would be wonderful.

I have **50 origins** for tree seeds. Each origin has several recorded **climate variables** like average temperature, precipitaion, wind etc.
After a few years of experienting I have an averaged "bud break"-**point in time** like "day 109.87" for each origin group.
Now I would like to know if there are any correlations between these bud break points and any of the associated climate variables.

Hopefully I was able to name all the relevant aspects of this problem.

Which test should I use for this? Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect that at least some of those climatic variables are driving differences bud break time, why not do a regression analysis with bud break time as the response?

Answer (score 0):

Linear Models (or Generalized Linear Models, depending on the distribution of your variable *Point in time*) with *Point in time* as **predicted variable** and your different *climatic variables* (quantitative and qualitative) as **predictors** would be a good start I believe. It will allow you to determine which *climatic variable* has an effect on the bud break and how much this bud break depends on the predictors.